# Converting "nan" values to a different value different than 0 in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, nan

I have such a numpy matrix:

```
[[182 93 107 ..., nan nan -1]
 [182 93 107 ..., nan nan -1]
 [182 93 110 ..., nan nan -1]
 ..., 
 [188 95 112 ..., nan nan -1]
 [188 97 115 ..., nan nan -1]
 [188 95 112 ..., nan nan -1]]
```

I want to change nan values to a value different than zero. For this reason, I have used this technique:

```
x_train[np.isnan(x_train)] = -10
```

But I got this error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the
>   inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
>   the casting rule ''safe''.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: What is `x_train.dtype`?

Comment: x_train.dtype = object

Comment: Then this is your problem -- NumPy doesn't know what to call `nan` in your array of objects the way it would if they were all floats. We might need to know a bit more about how you're loading your data and what it looks like.

Comment: It is not a problem @xnx, I can change the dtype to a different type, don't worry. Can you tell me the slution if my dtype is string?

Comment: If the dtype is numeric, like float64, your code should work as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your initial array is of strings that can be meaningfully interpreted as `float`s, then you can convert with `astype`:

```
b = np.array([['182', '93', '107', 'nan', 'nan', '-1'],
 ['182', '93', '107', 'nan', 'nan', '-1'],
 ['182', '93', '110', 'nan', 'nan', '-1'],
 ['188', '95', '112', 'nan', 'nan', '-1'],
 ['188', '97', '115', 'nan', 'nan', '-1'],
 ['188', '95', '112', 'nan', 'nan', '-1']])

c = b.astype(np.float)
c[np.isnan(c)]=-10

array([[ 182.,   93.,  107.,  -10.,  -10.,   -1.],
       [ 182.,   93.,  107.,  -10.,  -10.,   -1.],
       [ 182.,   93.,  110.,  -10.,  -10.,   -1.],
       [ 188.,   95.,  112.,  -10.,  -10.,   -1.],
       [ 188.,   97.,  115.,  -10.,  -10.,   -1.],
       [ 188.,   95.,  112.,  -10.,  -10.,   -1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [copyto](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html) function of numpy :

```
import numpy as np

xtrain = np.array([[0.3, np.nan],[1.0, np.nan]])
default = np.empty([2,2])
default.fill(-10)
print(xtrain)
np.copyto(xtrain,default,'no',np.isnan(xtrain))
print(xtrain)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use an array itterator, for exemple :

```
import numpy as np


a = np.empty((6,4))
a.fill(0.25)
a[2].fill(np.nan)      
for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    if np.isnan(x):
        x[...]=-10
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem.  It's just a slower way of doing the same thing.